# What media player can handle both music libraries (AAC, MP3) and videos (AVI, MKV,...)?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, music

Since iTunes is not capable of handling many video formats, I'm looking for an alternative that can replace iTunes, Quicktime and VLC.

What media player for OSX is able to:

- organize a large music library (ACC, MP3)
- play videos encoded in (AVI, MKV)

Comment: BTW: I do not need epic sync capabilities. Just the functionality to handle both music and videos really well. :)

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your [post I de-wikified](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37421/what-media-players-for-macosx-can-you-recommend) earlier today. I had left that one open, but would you prefer I closed it?

Comment: @KyleCronin Yeah, I thought the other one was closed? You can remove the other one. I tried to remove it myself just now - but it wasn't possible. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Nathan closed it for a bit, without realizing I had edited it, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only hits your second requirement but, if you ask me, it's the more important of the two by a long shot: [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). It can play just about anything you throw at it. It has support for play lists (both building and saving them) but it does not do any organization of your media. It is strictly a player.

Comment: Considering that the OP is looking for "an alternative that can replace iTunes, Quicktime and VLC," I think VLC is not an option. :)

Comment: Some things have no equal. :)

Comment: Maybe so, but he did specify that it was, among other things, to replace VLC…

Comment: Hey man, feel free to put up your own suggestion and down vote mine if you don't like it. Your comments aren't really adding anything to it...

Comment: VLC v2 handles media libraries more user friendly. Now this answer is accepted :)

Comment: Ha. Wait long enough and the technology catches up to my answer. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

You could check both Plex and XBMC, both are very capable media manager and player systems. Both are originally designed for use on a TV with a remote control. They are fully useable on the desktop though.

Plex : http://plexapp.com
XBMC : http://xbmc.org

Comment: Ha! Both websites participate in the protests against SOPA and PIPA. I'll check them out again tomorrow. :)

Comment: I'd just like to add that Plex is a very pushy program. It does work, and it works quite well, but it can take over your system in sometimes worrisome ways.